# BotLab MVC Route doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've just downloaded the BotLab code from the Rock,Paper,Azure site and am toying with it, but am unable to get one of the routes to work.  Here they are:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "GameLog",
                "GameLog/{teamName}.vs.{otherTeamName}",
                new { controller = "GameLog", action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "None",
                 "",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
            );
        }
```

If I try to navigate to the `~/GameLog/Something.vs.SomethingElse` url, I get a 404.  If I go to the `~/GameLog/` url, it hits the default route.  I don't really understand why the first route wouldn't match `~/GameLog/Something.vs.SomethingElse`.

So, just for compliance with Jeopardy rules, why doesn't the first route work as expected?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question but... Your last route should be defined first otherwise it will never get hit because "Default" one will server it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my first route never matched because I was running MVC 2 and should have been running MVC 3.  Once I installed MVC 3 and the updated VS tools, it worked as expected.